# Same Worksheet_Activate Code But With Different Ranges Not Working on Sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, I know nothing about macros and vba used in Excel and other applications. I copied from the internet and ran the following code in sheet 1 as:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Dim r As Range, c As Range
  Set r = Range("a129:a1675")
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each c In r
    If Len(c.Text) = 0 Then
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
      c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
  Next c

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code is working fine in Sheet 1 but the same code but with different range,i.e. "a5:a100" is not working for sheet 2.

Do we need to deactivate the code for sheet 1?

Thanks in Advance,
Regards,
ID

Comment: This is quite hard to read, please consider adding code blocks.

Comment: Yes. An Activate event occurs when one sheet is activated. You can't activate more than one sheet at a time. The code runs when its event occurs, and that occurrence is limited to the sheet that has the code. Sheets that don't have code to run on their Activate event miss the opportunity of doing something when they are activated.

Comment: Check out the workbook sheet activate event.

Answer (score 0):

You might create one sub like this one and place it in a standard code module, for example `Module1' (you will have to insert it: Right-click in the Project explorer while selecting the workbook's VBA project, select`Insert`and`Module`).

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideRows(Rng As Range)

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Rng
            Set Ws = .Worksheet
            For R = 1 To .Rows.Count
                Ws.Rows(.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = Not CBool(Len(.Cells(R)))
            Next R
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Then call that same sub from all the worksheets to be affected, each one with a different range as argument.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    HideRows Range("A1:A1675")
End Sub
```

The idea is that the range should have only one column. If you feed a multi-column range the `Hidden` status of the row will depend upon the last cell's content in each row.